# elisp: silence "Loading" messages in batch mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

Even when I invoke `emacs -batch` (that is, batch mode without actually doing anything), emacs vomits out a whole pile of messages:

```
$ emacs -batch
Loading 00debian-vars...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50autoconf.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50cmake-data.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50devhelp.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50dictionaries-common.el (source)...
Loading debian-ispell...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-default.el (source)...
Loading /var/cache/dictionaries-common/emacsen-ispell-dicts.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50psvn.el (source)...
```

Is there any way to silence these messages? Google hasn't been too helpful for this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are the messages that would normally show up in the `*Messages*` buffer, which are instead going to stderr. Here are a few ways to silence it, in increasing order of sophistication:

- The simplest fix would be to redirect stderr, if you're not going to use it:

  ```
  emacs -batch 2>/dev/null
  ```
- Those messages are coming from something loaded in the [site-wide initialization](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Init-File.html). If you don't need any other functionality from your initialization files, you can try:

  ```
  emacs -batch --no-site-file ... # ignore system-wide
  emacs -batch -Q ... # ignore everything
  ```
- In theory one can achieve this via `(setq force-load-messages nil)`, but the fact that the site-file is the one printing here means you likely can't do it early enough.
- advise the `load` function so that it is always called with `NOMESSAGE`. Here's a sketch:

  ```
  (defadvice load (before quiet-loading
                     (&optional NOMESSAGE)
                     activate)
     (setq NOMESSAGE t))
  (load site-run-file t)
  ```

  This should just force load to always pass `t` in the `NOMESSAGE` argument, and then loads the `site-run-file`, ignoring errors if no such file is present. (Note that at least on all 2 of the machines I use emacs on, there's no `site-run-file`; I have no idea how common that is in the wild.)

Comment: Good advice. I want to make a quiet makefile snippet that compiles elisp files. Redirecting stderr isn't a great idea because I want error messages to still be printed. The messages definitely come from site-wide elisp, because `-Q` silences them. I'm not sure if that's smart, because the elisp being compiled might require things loaded from the site-file.

Comment: I totally don't know your context, but I would guess that most elisp will actually do some work to `require` what it needs. My impression is that the site-file is mostly used for customizations in emacs sessions, not batch mode.

Comment: The context is here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake-patches/2012-07/msg00147.html , I am trying to write a Makefile suffix rule to compile elisp.

Comment: Unfortunately debian patched emacs' `startup.el` to load their own stuff, and writing elisp to detect the presence of debian and reimplement their loading process is off the table. Still, this is the correct answer, so enjoy your tick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: minor point, but force-load-messages does just that; so you can't use it to suppress the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I went source-diving and found that the `load` function calls the C function `message_from_string` to display the `"Loading <whatever>..."` messages.  When Emacs is not running interactively, `message_from_string` just prints directly to `stderr` with no way to avoid it.  Well, you could call the original `load` function with the `nomessage` parameter set to true, but it's probably not trivial to arrange that when running in batch mode.

It might suffice just to filter out the messages you don't want:

```
$ emacs -batch 2>&1 | grep -v '^Loading.*\.\.\.$'
```

Comment: Nice work. Do you know if it's possible to trigger the normal loading of the site-file (the one that is stopped by `-Q`)? If so, I might be able to pass `-Q`, put some advice on `(load)` and then kick off the normal loading process.

Comment: You should be able to load the site-file with just `(load site-run-file)`. Given that, I think your solution with `-Q` and some advice on `load` is absolutely the way to go; I'm happy to sketch the advice if you've never written any before.

Comment: @CraigCitro: That looks like the best way to go, can you write up a sketch as a new answer? When I do `emacs -Q -batch --eval "(load site-run-file)"`, I get the error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

Comment: @JackKelly: I ended up adding it to the previous.